# Deploy de Django en Virtualhost

Tags: django, djangorestframework, apache2, virtualhost, ubuntu-server

Estoy tratando de montar un proyecto de django en un servidor linux (Ubuntu 20.04)
Necesito montar el proyecto en el puerto 8000 y estoy utilizando VirtualHost de apache, pero el navegador retorna 403 Forbidden y el log muestra AH01630: client denied by server configuration /home/projects/myproject/myapp.

Ya corrobore los permisos, la ruta del DocumentRoot y el Required grant del directorio. Pero aun así continua el error 403 al acceder a la IP:8000

(myproject es el directorio donde esta **manage.py** y myapp es donde esta **wsgi.py**)

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
        ServerName djangoapi.com
        ServerAlias www.djangoapi.com
        DocumentRoot /home/projects/myproject
        ErrorLog /home/projects/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /home/projects/logs/access.log combined
        <Directory /home/projects/myproject>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/projects/myproject/myapp>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
        WSGIDaemonProcess backend python-path=/home/projects/myproject python-home=/home/projects/myproject/env
        WSGIProcessGroup backend
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/projects/myproject/myapp/wsgi.py
        Alias /static /home/projects/myproject/static
        <Directory /home/projects/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
        Alias /media /home/projects/myproject/media
        <Directory /home/projects/myproject/media>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sólamente se me ocurren un par de cosas:

- Desplegar de sites-available a sites-enabled con a2ensite.
- Reiniciar el servicio de apache (sudo systemctl restart apache2)
- Modificar el archivo /etc/hosts de tu sistema anfitrión con la configuración que diste de host.